# 'New' Button is Missing from Visual Studio's Connection Manager OLE DB Destination Editor

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl, oledbdestination

A user is missing the new button (highlighted in the snapshot) that appears for me in the Connection Manager's OLE DB Destination Editor in Visual Studio.  The user is a sysadmin on the database.

[image: example button]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That doesn't seem like an effective long-term solution. However, you might check what your permission is verse your coworkers. SysAdmin vs ???

Answer (score 0):

### Trying to figure out the issue

The following steps are some possible solution:

1. Visual Studio installation should be repaired or need to be updated
2. Change the package `TargetServerVersion` property [to the relevant SQL Server version](https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001710233-How-to-change-TargetServerVersion-of-my-SSIS-Project).
3. A third party extension is causing this issue, you can try to run Visual Studio in safe mode using the following command:

   ```
   devenv.exe /safemode
   ```
4. It could be a rendering issue, try changing the screen resolution

Answer (score 0):

Are you connected the destination before you edit it?
If no try to connect it first then edit, it works for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).